# R Data frame with empty entries

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which has a column with some valid entries, some blank entries, and some entries with NA. I want to know which entries have either blank or NA. How do I do this?

One idea I had was to convert the blank entries to NA and then find the entries with NA, but how do I do this conversion?

Comment: `which(df == "" | is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)` would be my guess.  But without a reproducible example it would be a waste of time to go any further.

Comment: Your blank entries are empty strings, or they may be spaces as well?

Comment: This is why it's a waste of time to proceed to try and solve this without a repro example.

Comment: Maybe we ought to create a service that will restrict users (maybe with low rep) to post a question If a reproducible example is not detected.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
nas <- which(is.na(df$col))
emptystrs <- which(df$col == "")
nas_or_empty <- which(is.na(df$col)|df$col == "")
```